# Splitting an image to be used as a website background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently doing a project which is an interative website for a "company". My idea was to use an image of the company room, where they work and use it as the background for the website. The problem is that i wanna do it like a point and click game, where i move my mouse and as soon as I step into something it will pop up information about that something. For example, a written board at the bottom right side of the picture talks about a meeting they are doing, so as soon as my mouse goes over that board it would pop up something talking about that meeting. My difficulty is that i don't know how to "split" the image into those small things (the board, the 3 desks, the posters on the wall...).

The idea is to use an html base and use JavaScript auxiliated by jQuery.
Any help would be appreciated :)

PS: can't post the image because I still don't have 10 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp) has pretty much example what you want. You can use css `:hover` on the areas to detect when the mouse moves over them.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh, nice. I knew about hover, but since i have 2 weeks to make this, and I had to learn all this new languages i just crossed the hover path a few times, and it never talked about coordinates.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: They are 2 separate things and are very rarely combined ;) Area doesn't come up that frequently so not a lot of people know about it! Very welcome, when you get the chance could you accept this as the answer?

Comment: Pedro.  It's call Image Mapping It's been around since 1996 so it's 20 year old technology. It was really popular back then.  Not so much now.